# android ¿como guardar la sesión de google iniciada en mi app?

Tags: android, sqlite

Buen día.

Estoy construyendo una app con android, estoy en la parte de inicio de sesión, en la cual quiero que inicie la sesión por google , esto ya lo hice , pero el problema es que cuando el usuario inicia la sesión y cierra la aplicación, la sesión se destruye y vuelve a pedir logueo.
Quisiera saber como puedo guardar esa sesión para que se mantenga aunque el usuario cierre la aplicación, y que únicamente se destruya cuando el usuario decida destruirla (logout).
De antemano gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilizes firebase

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando el google Sign-in

El mismo SDK realiza el guardado de los datos, este es un ejemplo de una `Activity` que implementa  `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`, la variable `result` que es un tipo `GoogleSignInResult` contiene los datos de tu autenticación, si es que fue realizada con anterioridad:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

a partir de `GoogleSignInResult`  podemos acceder a los datos, por ejemplo:

GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

```
Log.i("Google Sign in","DisplayName(): " + acct.getDisplayName());
Log.i("Google Sign in","Email: " + acct.getEmail());
Log.i("Google Sign in","IdToken: " + acct.getIdToken());
```

En cuanto al comentario de @FrancoLondra, Acerca de [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), la implementación es muy sencilla y una de las ventajas es que puedes autenticar con diversas comunidades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]